# docker scan <REPOSITORY>:<TAG> - failed to get DockerScanID: bad status code "400 Bad Request"

Tags: docker, snyk

I am trying to run

```
docker scan <REPOSITORY>:<TAG>
```

but it fails with error

```
failed to get DockerScanID: bad status code "400 Bad Request"
```

notes:

- I'm logged in to hub.docker.com
  [image]
- I created a token in docker which I use in snyk.com

I probably miss something else... any clues? thanks

Comment: Encountering the same message on ubuntu 20.04. Initially docker scan --version returned 0.8.0.   I ran apt update and apt upgrade, which resulted in installation of docker scan plugin 0.9.0.  I still get the same error. FWIW:  My system runs behind a corporate proxy that performs SSL inspection.  Could that be involved?

Comment: sorry. I don't know. I was able to fix as indicated in the answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

you have to log in to snyk via the cli:

```
docker scan --login
```

then you have to enter the credentials in the browser. after that you are able to run

```
docker scan <REPOSITORY>:<TAG>
```

note: responding with a `400` error is a bit misleading. responding with a `401` or `403` (and maybe even saying `you have to authenticate with "docker scan --login"` would have made it more human readable :|

Comment: I had tried these steps.  I entered the URL given on the command line after running the docker scan --login  but that same command also outputs "An unknown error occurred. Please run with `-d` and include full trace when reporting to Snyk". I try adding -d as directed and get an error that -d is an unknown shorthand flag.

Comment: that looks like a related error but definitely a differnt one. if you are unable to find a solution, maybe handle it directly with snyk support.

Comment: Its weird why a simple if not logged: login() is not implemented there?  definitely the "you have to log first" would be much human friendly :D